# Correct pattern to call more times a method

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, object, constructor

```
function Class(pro_1,pro_2,pro_3,pro_4,pro_5,pro_6) {
    this.prop1 = prop_1;
    this.prop2 = prop_2;
    this.prop3 = prop_3;
    this.prop4 = prop_4;
    this.prop5 = prop_5;
    this.prop6 = prop_6;

    this.method = function(){}

}

// READY
$(document).ready(function () {
    var foo = new Class('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4','value5','value6');
    foo.method();
});

// RESIZE
$(window).resize(function () {
    foo.method();
});
```

1) I need call method "foo" more times. Is it correct call it as in the above code?

2) I have many parameters to be passed to the "Class". What is the correct way to handle this?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean "I need to call foo _more_ times"? Best way I know to do this is `while(true){ foo.method(); }` :)

Comment: sorry @JeremyThille. I mean the foo.method();

Comment: My question was about the MORE times. Define "more".

Comment: this method calculate the width of some element. And it must work on load of document and during resize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the resize handler in the same DOM ready handler as the creation:

e.g.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var foo = new Class('value1', 'value2', 'value3', 'value4','value5','value6');
    foo.method();
    // RESIZE
    $(window).resize(function () {
        foo.method();
    });
});
```

You can't use `foo` before it is created and a `resize` event handler is just as happy inside a DOM ready event handler.

2. You either pass lots of simple parameters, or combine them into an object.

   ```
   var foo = new Class({ val1: 'value1', 
         val2: 'value2', 
         val3: 'value3', 
         val4: 'value4',
         val5: 'value5',
         val6: 'value6'
   });
   ```

then your class becomes simpler:

```
function Class(options) {
    this.options = options;
    this.method = function(){}
}
```

Comment: Or: `$(window).resize(foo.method);`

Comment: @Jonathan: true. I do not want to change their code too much in one go (more to explain then).

Comment: @Jonathan inside ready?
'code'
$(document).ready(function () {
$(window).resize(foo.method);
})
'code'

Comment: @Jonathan : See what I mean about confusing them :)

Comment: @Jonathan not knowing what `this.method` does, I would not recommend that since `this` will be altered.

Comment: @Stefano Vollono: Do you have any questions for *me* about *my* answer, rather than about comments getting posted here? :)

Comment: @TrueBlueAussie your example it's ok. I will use that method. thx